# Optimize HTML page with a TON of links

Tags: html, xml, hyperlink

I maintain an HTML page that contains a list of links to photo galleries. Over the past few years it has gone from a small page to a list that contains HUNDREDS of links. My fear is that it has affected the SEO of the page as a whole; being interpeted by spiders as a link farm. Of course, I have no real way of knowing fo sure but I have started to suspect.

Is there an efficient simple way to deal with a large number of links in a manner that is still easy for the user to browse? While having hundreds of links one of top of the other may not be the best looking method, its easy to search since they are all in chronological order. I am looking to figure out a way that I can keep the page simple without creating more of a maintenance nightmare for myself.

One idea I had was use XML to store the links and use some kind of dropdown so that when a spider hit the page it would not see a mountain of links, just a reference to XML

Comment: You could ajax them into separate divs depending on how you want them to be sorted. You could probably then add a dropdown box to further provide a nice UI for your website showing only the contents on each div depending on the user selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "pager" script to show, say 10 at a time.  They are available in every web framework or you could quickly hack up your own.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I am going to look into this method first as it looks like I might be able to implement it the simplest and I like the idea of paging.

Answer (score 1):

... how about this. Put links in separate file(s) (or somehow store them outside of the page, db, flat file, etc.) and load them via ajax call as needed. Say, something like 'Category A' button, when clicked loads links into a div. That should keep it out view for spiders.

Then there's this: http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow